# What software can help me to draw a graph of the Internet connection getting connected.. disconnected ... etc

Tags: linux, windows, networking

One of my customers is using a certain device connected to the internet, he is not sure if the device is not functioning properly or its the internet connection thats going up and down, connected disconnected, online off line and so one
Is there a certain software that can help me to visualize that? as in a graph or something like that?

thanks

Comment: How is this going to help you? Once you see a log saying: at time so and so you were connected, later you were disconnected, how is this helpful?

Comment: this will convince my client that its not the device's fault and he'll get a better internet connection

Comment: Apologies, I still don't get it: when he sees the disconnections, how will he know it is the provider's fault rather than the equipment's? You cannot deduce that from such a graph, just the percentage of uptime.

Comment: the device is connected to the router, it keeps going offline, its either the device or the connection, we trust the router. I've plugged my laptop into the router and showed his how Pings go down

Comment: if u are using windows 8 you could check by taskmanager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WireShark is a piece of software that monitors all network traffic on the computers, writing it to a log. You can find it here: http://www.wireshark.org/. You should note that these logs tend to get VERY verbose, and take up a lot of room. They can also be quite finicky to navigate to the uninitiated.

It exists for Windows, Linux and OS X, downloads here: http://www.wireshark.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use any connectivity monitor available on the market, or even simply use the `ping [IP_DEST]` command. If you really need something graphical, [InternetConnectivityMonitor](https://code.google.com/p/internetconnectivitymonitor/)may be a good start, but you can find thousands of similar software on Internet.